# Declaration of more that one lists object at once

Tags: c#, declaration

I wanted to know if i have few list obejcts in my code, if i want to declare all the lists in one line is it equal to declaration in seperate lines:

```
ListA = ListB = ListC ... = new List<MyType>();
```

**is it equal to:**

```
ListA = new List<MyType>();
ListB = new List<MyType>();
ListC = new List<MyType>();
...
```

I must be sure i will have no aliasing issue that way

Comment: None of those are a declaration.  They are simply assignment statements.  And, no, they are not equivalent.  The first one creates a new list object (`new List<MyType>()`) and assigns a reference to that new object to each of the variables `ListA`, `ListB`, and  `ListC` (remember, `List<T>` is a reference type - all three variables will now reference the same object).  The second example creates three new list objects, and assigns a reference to each of the new lists to each of your variables.  In this case, the three variables all reference different objects

Comment: When you tried your sample code and examined the results, what were they that prompted you to ask the question here?

Comment: @Flydog57 - seems like you pointed it out corretly Thanks!

Comment: @Rufus L - As part of investigating wierd behavior after code refactoring.

Comment: Reducing code complexity is a good reason to do refactoring. Just blindly reducing lines of code can result in faulty results.  It's good to read up on the difference between value types and reference types.  If you had three int variables, A, B and C, and you had this line of code: `A=B=C=42`, then you'd have each of the three int variables initialized to the number 42.  But, with `List<T>` being a reference type, your first code initializes your three variables so that they all *reference* the same object (the one that your `new` expression created. `ListA.Add(x)` would be visible in `ListC`

Comment: correct, so any object which have a refference type this way will have the same behavior as List<T> which will point to the same created new Object right?

Answer (score 0):

as Flydog57 commented out, the assignment reffers to the same object in the 1st example,
and create new instance on the 2nd example.